# Poner un numero a una cadena de caracteres java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que asigne a cada letra del abecedario un numero, todo correlativo, es decir a=1, b=2, c=3... siempre en minúsculas y sin la ñ. Para *abcd* la salida sería 10, o para *adef* la salida 16. El código que tengo es:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class palabras {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escriba una cadena.");
    String x = teclado.nextLine();
    int s = x.length();
    int f = 0;
    char t;
    for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {
        t = x.charAt(i);
        for (char a = 'a'; a <= t; a++) {

        }
        f = f+i;

    }
    System.out.println(f);

  }
}
```

Se que lo que tengo mal es el for, que si meto *af*, me sale 3, cuando tendría que salirme 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte del código `ASCII`:

```
    int suma = 0;
    String cadena = "abcd";
    for (int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
      if ((int)cadena.charAt(i) != 164){
        suma += (int) cadena.charAt(i) - 96;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(suma);
```

Al pasar un `char` a `int`, Java lo convierte en su código ASCII.
`164` es el carácter `ñ`
Para comprobar que sólo mete un carácter de la `a` a la `z` podrías cambiar la línea de comprobación de la `ñ` por:

```
if ((int)cadena.charAt(i) >= 97 && (int)cadena.charAt(i) <= 122)
```

Aquí te dejo la tabla **[ASCII](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png)**